# Gson not parsing Class variable

Tags: java, gson

I am using Gson and I have an object that one of its fields is a Class

```
class A {
…
private Class aClass;
… }
```

When I parse the instance to Json using default Gson object aClass comes empty.

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have public getter/setter for aClass ?

Comment: Do you parse the Json into an object (JSON->Object) or convert the object to a Json string (Object->JSON)? If you're parsing Json, what does your `aClass` field look like?

Comment: GSON doesn't use getters/setters. It uses only fields in class.

Answer (score 8):

You need custom type adapter. Here is example:

```
package com.sopovs.moradanen;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class GsonClassTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Class.class, new ClassTypeAdapter())
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();

    String json = gson.toJson(new Foo());
    System.out.println(json);

    Foo fromJson = gson.fromJson(json, Foo.class);
    System.out.println(fromJson.boo.getName());
}

public static class ClassTypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Class<?>>, JsonDeserializer<Class<?>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Class<?> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return Class.forName(json.getAsString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

public static class Foo {
    Class<?> boo = String.class;
}
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
{
  "boo": "java.lang.String"
}
java.lang.String
```

Comment: You could throw a JsonParseException instead of RuntimeException.

Comment: **Warning:** Assuming the JSON data comes from untrusted users, this allows them to load arbitrary classes from the classpath and who knows what your application then does with these classes. In the worst case this can lead to a remote code execution vulnerability. Ideally restrict the class to some known safe subclass: `Class.forName(json.getAsString(), false, getClass().getClassLoader()).asSubclass(MyKnownBaseclass.class)`

Answer (score 3):

> When I parse the instance to Json using default Gson object aClass comes empty.
>
> Any idea why?

In [a comment in issue 340](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=340#c2), a Gson project manager explains:

> Serializing types is actually somewhat of a security problem, so we don't want to support it by default. A malicious .json file could cause your application to load classes that it wouldn't otherwise; depending on your class path loading certain classes could DoS your application.
>
> But it's quite straightforward to write a type adapter to support this in your own app.

Of course, since serialization is not the same as deserialization, I don't understand how this is an explanation for the disabled serialization, unless the unmentioned notion is to in a sense "balance" the default behaviors of serialization with deserialization.