# Why has gson does not allow serialization of java.lang.Class?

Tags: java, serialization, gson

If you try to serialize an object that has a field of type `java.lang.Class`, serializing it will lead to `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: <some_class> Forgot to register a type adapter`

Below is the code snippet from com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters.java

```
public final class TypeAdapters {
.
.
.
  public static final TypeAdapter<Class> CLASS = new TypeAdapter<Class>() {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Class value) throws IOException {
      if (value == null) {
        out.nullValue();
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: "
            + value.getName() + ". Forgot to register a type adapter?");
      }
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Was this coded in gson just to remind people if they "Forgot to register a type adapter"?

As I see it, `Class` type object could have easily been serialized and deserialized using the following statements:

Serialize : `clazz.getName()`

Deserialize : `Class.forName(className)`

What could the reason behind the current implementation be? Where am I wrong in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson not parsing Class variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119138/gson-not-parsing-class-variable)

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Seems like the question is asking the same question. I suppose the description in my question clears some confusions. I'll use the answer there to answer this question myself.

Answer (score 2):

as answered by @Programmer Bruce [Gson not parsing Class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119138/gson-not-parsing-class-variable) -

In a [comment in issue 340](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/340#c2), a Gson project manager explains:

> Serializing types is actually somewhat of a security problem, so we
>   don't want to support it by default. A malicious .json file could
>   cause your application to load classes that it wouldn't otherwise;
>   depending on your class path loading certain classes could DoS your
>   application.
>
> But it's quite straightforward to write a type adapter to support this
>   in your own app.

Of course, since serialization is not the same as

deserialization, I don't understand how this is an explanation for the
disabled serialization, unless the unmentioned notion is to in a sense
"balance" the default behaviors of serialization with deserialization.